# AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, httpresponse

I am working on a legacy django project, in there somewhere there is a class defined as follows;

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class Response(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, template='', calling_context='' status=None):
        self.template = template
        self.calling_context = calling_context
        HttpResponse.__init__(self, get_template(template).render(calling_context), status)
```

and this class is used in views as follows

```
def some_view(request):
    #do some stuff
    return Response('some_template.html', RequestContext(request, {'some keys': 'some values'}))
```

this class was mainly created so that they could use it to perform assertions in the unit tests .i.e they are not using django.test.Client to test the views but rather they create a mock request and pass that to view as(calling the view as a callable) in the tests as follows

```
def test_for_some_view(self):
    mock_request = create_a_mock_request()
    #call the view, as a function
    response = some_view(mock_request) #returns an instance of the response class above
    self.assertEquals('some_template.html', response.template)
    self.assertEquals({}, response.context)
```

The problem is that half way through the test suite(quite a huge test suite), some tests begin blowing up when executing the

```
return Response('some_template.html', RequestContext(request, {'some keys': 'some values'}))
```

and the stack trace is

```
self.template = template
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

the full stack trace looks something like

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_should_list_all_users_for_that_specific_sales_office
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/austiine/Projects/mped/console/metrics/tests/unit/views/sales_office_views_test.py",   line 106, in test_should_list_all_users_for_that_specific_sales_office
    response = show(request, sales_office_id=sales_office.id)
File "/Users/austiine/Projects/mped/console/metrics/views/sales_office_views.py", line 63, in show
    "sales_office_users": sales_office_users}))
File "/Users/austiine/Projects/mped/console/metrics/utils/response.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.template = template
    AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

the actual failing test is

```
def test_should_list_all_users_for_that_specific_sales_office(self):
    user_company = CompanyFactory.create()
    request = self.mock_request(user_company)
    #some other stuff

    #calling the view
    response = show(request, sales_office_id=sales_office.id)
    self.assertIn(user, response.calling_context["sales_office_users"])
    self.assertNotIn(user2, response.calling_context["sales_office_users"])
```

code for the show view

```
def show(request, sales_office_id):
    user = request.user
    sales_office = []
    sales_office_users = []
    associated_market_names = []
    try:
        sales_office = SalesOffice.objects.get(id=sales_office_id)
        sales_office_users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__sales_office=sales_office)
        associated_market_names = Market.objects.filter(id__in=           (sales_office.associated_markets.all())).values_list("name", flat=True)
        if user.groups.all()[0].name == UserProfile.COMPANY_AO:
            associated_market_names = [market.name for market in sales_office.get_sales_office_user_specific_markets(user)]
        except:
            pass
    return Response("sales_office/show.html", RequestContext(request, {'keys': 'values'}))
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole traceback error message?

Comment: the biggest part of the stack trace is just a bunch of absolute paths for test file where the code blows up, the view and the actual file where the exception originates nevertheless i'll paste here

Comment: Try to print type(template) before self.template = template and tell me the print info.

Comment: print type(template) returns <type 'str'> and print type(self.template) returns *** AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'templates'

Comment: It seams to me that `self` in response have a read only attribute named `template`. Can you post `show()` method of `sales_office_views.py` module?

Comment: @Micheled'Amico yeah seems so to me as well but when i stick a pdb in the constructor and execute self.template i get "*** AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'templates" instead of something like *** AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'template'

Comment: @Micheled'Amico added the code for show at the bottom

Comment: repr(type(self).__dict__) will show the attributes of the Request instance. Is 'template' one of them?

Comment: @XORcist no, template does not exist when i put a pdb as the first line of the __init__ method and i execute that line, i "['__module__', '__doc__', '__init__']" and self.__dict__ is {}.

Comment: may be one thing i didnt clarify is that some test for views which are using the response class pass while others fail, thats whats weird

Answer (score 116):

This answer doesn't address the specifics of this question, but explains the underlying issue.
This specific exception "AttributeError: can't set attribute" is raised (see [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ff7132313eb651107b179d20218dfe5d4e47f13/Objects/descrobject.c#L1415)) when the attribute you're attempting to change is actually a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) that doesn't have a setter. If you have access to the library's code, adding a setter would solve the problem.

EDIT: updated source link to new location in the code.

Edit2:

Example of a setter:

```
class MAMLMetaLearner(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            args,
            base_model,

            inner_debug=False,
            target_type='classification'
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.args = args  # args for experiment
        self.base_model = base_model
        assert base_model is args.model

        self.inner_debug = inner_debug
        self.target_type = target_type

    @property
    def lr_inner(self) -> float:
        return self.args.inner_lr

    @lr_inner.setter
    def lr_inner(self, new_val: float):
        self.args.inner_lr = new_val
```

Comment: I suppose it should be considered an achievement, having my answer get a negative score, while all the others are at zero. I'm "absolutely" better. :)

Comment: "source" link is 404, but in the current code I found properties [here as python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ff7132313eb651107b179d20218dfe5d4e47f13/Objects/descrobject.c#L1278), or as the [actual C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ff7132313eb651107b179d20218dfe5d4e47f13/Objects/descrobject.c#L1415)

Comment: Is it possible to have a property without a setter?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, sure, that's exactly the issue in the question. A property is read-only unless a setter is explicitly provided.

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need to set a setter I thought in python we were free to do whatever we wanted...I've set random fields before why is this one giving me issues? https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/96#issuecomment-771982784

Comment: @CharlieParker, you're right in general, but in this case, by using the `@property` decorator, the library's developer intentionally limited the ability to set that attribute. Here's a relevant question for a similar use case - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/371540/should-a-python-property-decorator-be-used-without-a-setter-or-deleter

Comment: @yoniLavi those stupid developers. Why would they do that!? (hint I did it... :/ , now I'm wondering why I did it and how to fix it...)

Comment: can you provide an example of adding a setter in python? Is it with a dectorator or something so that the `self.x = y` work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't use `self.template` in `Response` class. Try like this:

```
class Response(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, template='', calling_context='' status=None):
        HttpResponse.__init__(self, get_template(template).render(calling_context), status)
```

Comment: yes self.template is not used inside in the Response class, its used in tests for assertions like this; self.assertEquals('some_template.html', response.template) the same with calling_context

Comment: the whole response class is there for use in tests

Comment: @austiine So after deleting two lines, was there still the same error?

Comment: no that error goes away but my tests fail because they except response to have template and calling_context attributes

Answer (score 0):

I took a look to django source code I've no idea where `template` or `templates` attribute come from in `HttpResponse`. But I can propose to you to change your test approach and migrate to [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) framework. You can rewrite your test like:

```
@patch("qualified_path_of_response_module.response.Response", spec=Response)
def test_should_list_all_users_for_that_specific_sales_office(self,mock_resp):
    user_company = CompanyFactory.create()
    request = self.mock_request(user_company)
    #some other stuff

    #calling the view
    response = show(request, sales_office_id=sales_office.id)
    self.assertTrue(mock_resp.called)
    context = mock_resp.call_args[0][2]
    self.assertIn(user, context["sales_office_users"])
    self.assertNotIn(user2, context["sales_office_users"])
```

`@patch` decorator replace your `Response()` class by a `MagicMock()` and pass it to your test method as `mock_resp` variable. You can also use `patch` as context manager by `with` construct but decorators are the cleaner way to do it. I don't know if `Response` is just a stub class for testing but in that case you can patch directly `HttpResponce`, but it depends from your code.

You can find details about `call_args` [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_args). Maybe you need to use `spec` attribute because django make some type checking... but try with and without it (I'm not a django expert). Explore `mock` framework: it'll give to you lot of powerful tools to make simple tests.