# Convert string to property - AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror, setter, converters, namedtuple

I was running python code below:

```
def dict2struct(d):
    res = namedtuple("config", d.keys())(*d.values())
    return res

cfg = {'fieldx': 'Allan', "fieldy": 45, 'fieldt': {'head': False, 'number': 2}}
res = dict2struct(cfg)
print(res)
res.fieldx = "Jack"
```

and got the error:

```
config(fieldx='Allan', fieldy=45, fieldt={'head': False, 'number': 2})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****\Testings\test_x.py", line 97, in <module>
    res.fieldx = "Jack"
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I have read the questions below and understand that it was because `namedtuples` are immutable and the property setter was restricted.
[AttributeError: can't set attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396339/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute/27627094)
[AttributeError: can't set attribute in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562425/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-in-python/22562689)

However, I need to convert a lot of strings from a configurational dictionary's keys to properties of a struct or a class. These strings values are not fixed as they are many.

Is there a way to get around of this `AttributeError` for my problem?

Comment: Can't you just edit the original Dictionary and then call the dict2struct() function again?

Comment: So are you looking for a dictionary-like object that lets you set key/value pairs via `x.key = value`?  I wrote one of those a long time ago that I've been using ever since.  I was just googling around, and didn't find anything similar that didn't come as part of a huge collection of stuff.  I'm surprised.  I wonder if someone else knows of one of these available in the wild pretty much on its own.  Maybe I should publish mine :)

Comment: @Steve, the input I have is a dictionary with string keys. The output is supposed to be a struct / class so as to be used like: res.fieldx, res.fieldy, etc. Can you share a bit of your code of the conversion?

Comment: Ah.  Found it.  Is this what you want maybe? - https://pypi.org/project/attributedict/

Comment: This sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: @Steve attributedict works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve's solution above worked for me.
[pypi.org/project/attributedict](http://pypi.org/project/attributedict)